# Find two numbers that add up to target

Tags: java, performance, programming-challenge

I am trying to solve [this problem](https://oj.leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/):

> Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

and this is my implementation:

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] numbers, int target) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> numbersMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    int[] requiredNumbers = null;
    int index = 0;
    for (int number : numbers) {
        if (numbersMap.containsKey(target - number)) {
            requiredNumbers = new int[2];
            requiredNumbers[0] = numbersMap.get(target - number);
            requiredNumbers[1] = index;
            return requiredNumbers;
        } else {
            numbersMap.put(number, index);
            index++;
        }
    }
    return requiredNumbers;
}
```

How can I improve its execution time?

Comment: you could have used indexed for loop as you are anyway keeping the track of the index

Answer (score 2):

If the size of your input array can be **large**, you can get a speed-up by preallocating the capacity of your `HashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> numbersMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(numbers.length * 2);
```

As the algorithm runs, data will be added to the `HashMap`.  When number of entries exceeds the `capacity * load_factor`, the hashmap's capacity is doubled, and the elements are re-binned for the larger capacity.  This capacity doubling and rebinning takes time.  It doesn't happen often, \$O(\log N)\$ times, but it can be eliminated by starting with a hashmap of sufficient capacity.

The `load_factor` defaults to 0.75, so an initial capacity larger than `numbers.length * 4/3` is required.  `numbers.length * 2` is a simple expression that satisfies that requirement.